# Apache localhost problem

Tags: apache-2.2

I have set up Apache on my Windows 7 PC. Now I have it working fine on the PC, by going to localhost or the IP (192.168.1.71). However when I go to my Mac I try to connect to it via its IP and it doesn't connect. I have also tried this on another computer.

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.71

Now is there something wrong with the code in the Apache httpd file?

EDIT:

I have also tried to ping the IP address and it works fine.

Comment: Can the mac ping the IP? Is your windos firewall configured to aceept connections on port 80? Can apache open other ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the Windows firewall blocks external connections to port 80. You should explicitly open the port in the configuration.